# Adjust Position of Text with CSS

Tags: css, joomla3.0

I need to move the text shown in the slide component in order to center it.

Here is the site: http://cmarosac-cp52.webjoomla.es/fav/

The class is: flex-caption

```
.flex-caption {
width: 25%;
height: 96%;
padding: 2%; 
margin: 0; 
position: absolute; 
left: 0; 
bottom: 0; 
background: rgba(0,0,0,.3); 
color: #fff; 
text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.3); 
font-size: 14px; 
line-height: 20px;
}
```

Comment: That's nice. Good luck figuring it out. Did you have a question?

Comment: you should use the new joomla.stackexchange.com for joomla questions.

Answer (score 0):

Change left to `left: 35%;` in your CSS.

```
.flex-caption {
width: 25%;
height: 96%;
padding: 2%;
margin: 0;
position: absolute;
left: 35%;
bottom: 0;
background: rgba(0,0,0,.3);
color: #fff;
text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.3);
font-size: 14px;
line-height: 20px;
}
```

To center the text in the shadow, add `text-align: center;`.

To position the text as near to vertical center as possible while keeping the box shadow intact as part of the same class:

```
.flex-caption {
width: 25%;
height: auto;
padding: 2%;
margin: 0;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
background: rgba(0,0,0,.3);
color: #fff;
text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.3);
font-size: 14px;
line-height: 20px;
padding-top: 50%;
top: -70%;
text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: The shadow-box is part of the `.flex-caption` CSS. So just remove the background from the CSS and you won't have a shadow-box.

Comment: But I need the shadow-box... and the place is correct, left:0, width25% and height:96%.... The problems is that I need center the text... and now the text is displayed on the top ¿?

Comment: Center the text in the container or the shadow?

Comment: Then just use `text-align: center;` instead.

Comment: Nop... because this align the text in horizontal... I need center the text in vertical direction.

Comment: You need to be very specific with your questions.

Comment: Steve's answer is the only one that will work. You have to separate the text from the box. I updated my answer to get you as close to center as possible without editing the module.

Comment: OK, my problema now is that I can't locate the file to add the span tag. The component doesn't have any default.php or similar...

Answer (score 0):

html

```
<div class="flex-caption">
     <span>Podemos poner tantas imágenes como queramos, hasta un máximo de 10</span>
</div>
```

css

```
.flex-caption {
    width: 25%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 20px;
    height: 100%;
}
.flex-caption span{
    -moz-transform: translate(0,-50%);
    -o-transform: translate(0,-50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(0,-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, -50%);
    transform: translate(0, -50%);
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    padding: 0 20px;
    text-align: left;
}
```

hope this helps:)

Comment: Steve, could you locate, with firebug, the path for the HTML file that I have to edit? I´m new  with this...

Comment: You can use global search function of your development tool to find the path of the HTML file which is contain the specify text. For example, search the text which is bottom of the banners (i.e. "AQUÍ PODEMOS PONER UN SLOGAN O FRASE RELEVANTE")

Comment: The text is introduced in the configuration form of a Joomla module... then, I cant do a search by the text in order to add span tag